# Azure policy to evaluate compliance of a dependent resource

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have a requirement to prevent creating a VM if the assigned Subnet (existing subnet) is not comply with a specific policy definition. I understand that I can prevent creating the subnet but if the subnet already exists, how can I prevent VMs from using it.

I have a policy that audits if subnet has NSG and the NSG has internet access enabled. So if any VM is trying to use this NSG it should be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent creating a VM of existing subnet with a specific policy definition. check the below work arounds:

Create a policy definition use below **JSON** to prevent vm like below:

[image]

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "in": [
            "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          ]
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
            },
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].destinationAddressPrefix",
          "equals": "*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Assign the policy, If you want to deny the vm creation change the `effect = deny`.

[image]

After assigning the policy you can see that NSG with existing subnet which has internet access, it is marked as non-compliant successfully like below:

[image]

***Note***: This policy only applies to new VM creations. This policy does not automatically delete or prevent a VM from using a non-compliant subnet if it is already doing so. Only new VMs using non-compliant subnets will be prevented from being created.

Comment: in fact my issue is in users using a non-Complient subnet. What I want is disallow both creating a a VM with new subnet with open inbound internet access (*) or VM using existing subnet that has open inbound internet access.

Comment: Add this code in your policy "existenceCondition": { "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/securityRules[*].destinationAddressPrefix", "equals": "*" } and also change the setting the effect to "deny" and specifying the existence condition based on the subnet's security rules, this policy will prevent the creation of a VM with a new subnet that has open inbound internet access (*)